# Get rid of all the access white space except the actual design

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a way that I can get rid of all the extra white space apart from the rectangle shown in the image.

Please let me know if I need to provide some extra input.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *File > Document Setup*
2. Click on the *Edit Artboards* button
3. Click and drag until the artboard is the desired size

[image]